# SSRS Save as Excel shows line for Page Header

Tags: ssrs-2012

I have an SSRS RDL file. I added Page Header and a tablix to display data in grid.

When I run the report and save as excel, at the page header, there is a continuous line in the excel. 
How do I remove this extra line?

Please help.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of the issue?  Possibly the design view of the report as well?

Answer (score 0):

Found out that the Page Header is displayed in excel with Freeze Panes option. Excel will show the black line, when the panes are frozen. Thank you.